# Rendering text using piston in rust

Tags: rust, text, rust-piston

I'm trying to learn how to use the piston library for rust, and I don't know how to render text.

When trying to render text, only the first letter appears. I tried looking online but there aren't a lot of example about piston, and they didn't seem to work for me.

Here is the code:

```
use piston_window::types::Color;
use piston_window::*;

const WIDTH: u32 = 1280;
const HEIGHT: u32 = 720;

pub fn draw_text(
    ctx: &Context,
    graphics: &mut G2d,
    glyphs: &mut Glyphs,
    color: Color,
    pos: [u32; 2],
    text: &str,
) {
    text::Text::new_color(color, 20)
        .draw(
            text,
            glyphs,
            &ctx.draw_state,
            ctx.transform.trans(pos[0] as f64, pos[1] as f64),
            graphics,
        )
        .unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let mut window: PistonWindow = WindowSettings::new("Ray Marching", [WIDTH, HEIGHT])
        .exit_on_esc(true)
        .graphics_api(OpenGL::V3_2)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    //Fonts
    let mut glyphs = window.load_font("assets/Coolvetica.otf").unwrap();

    while let Some(event) = window.next() {
        window.draw_2d(&event, |context, graphics, _device| {
            //Clear window
            clear([0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0], graphics);

            //Draw text
            draw_text(
                &context,
                graphics,
                &mut glyphs,
                [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [3, 20],
                "Hello World!",
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need `extern crate piston_window;` if you're using a very old compiler or compiling without `cargo` which is very much not recommended.

Comment: Can confirm that it only draws the first character.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the font? Did you try a different one? Like, maybe it has a broken stride or whatever the thing is called that defines the distance to the next character.

Comment: I've tried multiple fonts and it seems to be font independent. What I have noticed, though, is that it doesn't render only the **first** letter, but only the first run of **identical** letters. For example, when trying to render `1112223`, it will draw `111`.

Comment: I tried with 3 different fonts, and whatever the first character is, it will display it, but only the first one

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/piston_window/issues/258

Comment: Also when giving it a str that I created from the number of fps, it only renders a 0 when there is one which doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: oh that's interesting, I'll try changing version. edit: I tried changing version but I get a lot of errors with functions not existing so I'll try fixing that but idk if I can

Comment: In version 0.89.0 I can't even import the font xd

Comment: I meant, there is information in the issue link that is worth reading, not that you should try old versions :P

Comment: I found a fix, using the fix in the issue you mentionned, ty so much

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/piston_window/issues/258), it seems that it is required to flush the glyph cache at the end of the `draw_2d` closure.

Like this:

```rust
use piston_window::types::Color;
use piston_window::*;

const WIDTH: u32 = 1280;
const HEIGHT: u32 = 720;

pub fn draw_text(
    ctx: &Context,
    graphics: &mut G2d,
    glyphs: &mut Glyphs,
    color: Color,
    pos: [u32; 2],
    text: &str,
) {
    text::Text::new_color(color, 20)
        .draw(
            text,
            glyphs,
            &ctx.draw_state,
            ctx.transform.trans(pos[0] as f64, pos[1] as f64),
            graphics,
        )
        .unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let mut window: PistonWindow = WindowSettings::new("Ray Marching", [WIDTH, HEIGHT])
        .exit_on_esc(true)
        .graphics_api(OpenGL::V3_2)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    //Fonts
    let mut glyphs = window.load_font("assets/Coolvetica.otf").unwrap();

    while let Some(event) = window.next() {
        window.draw_2d(&event, |context, graphics, device| {
            //Clear window
            clear([0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0], graphics);

            //Draw text
            draw_text(
                &context,
                graphics,
                &mut glyphs,
                [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                [3, 20],
                "Hello World!",
            );

            glyphs.factory.encoder.flush(device);
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Success Screenshot]

Comment: Yep that works thank you :)